# Forking and changing an NPM package

Tags: npm, npm-install

I have been using an NPM for angular-4 which support drag and drop objects (ng2-drag-drop). I found a missing functionality and decide to add it to the package.

What I did is forking the original project and adding my changes. after commit/push to my git I then used the following command to install my NPM :

```
npm install https://github.com/..... --save
```

the NPM installed successfully however when looking in my node_modules I see that the source files are missing and I have only the root directory including the package.json and some other files . any source files are missing.

I then tried to instal the NPM directly from the author git so instead of running :

```
npm install ng2-drag-drop --save
```

I used

```
npm install https://github.com/ObaidUrRehman/ng2-drag-drop.git --save
```

and I had the same issue with my fork.

Why the installation is different between the author git and the named package ? isn't it taking the files from the same location ? if no, what should I do to make it work ?

Comment: did you try using 
`npm install https://github.com/yourforkedrepo/ng2-drag-drop.git --save`

Comment: what is the error the updated modules dont reflect ? can you please check your dependecies in package.json

Comment: @RahulSingh what do you mean ? the whole module isn't working when using the git repo directly. the sources are not there.

Comment: can you try  npm cache clean  then delete that from dependencies  and then install again

Comment: cleaning cache didn't work.

Comment: its strange i dnt think anything else is wrong with your code , i have done this and it works fine

Comment: you used npm install using the github project and under the node_modules you see ng2-drag-drop and a directly named src ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are not able to see the src folder is

If you see the git repo you will find two files 
`gitignore` & `npmignore`.

In that npm ignore file you will find the src has been ignored to be prevent it from being added to the package when running npm commands .

**Keeping files out of your package**

> Use a .npmignore file to keep stuff out of your package. If there's no
>   .npmignore file, but there is a .gitignore file, then npm will ignore
>   the stuff matched by the .gitignore file. If you want to include
>   something that is excluded by your .gitignore file, you can create an
>   empty .npmignore file to override it. Like git, npm looks for
>   .npmignore and .gitignore files in all subdirectories of your package,
>   not only the root directory.

You need to overwrite these settings to be able to get src contents in node modules when you do npm install

Comment: Why someone would like to ignore their source files ? is it a common practice or just a strange thing in this specific project ?

Comment: @Nuno_147 its strange for me but i just was going through a package i had overridden and figured out the npm ignore